How do I replace the values in a dataframe based other dataframe using pysaprk
I have a two dataframes in my databricks notebook. for example data looks like below:
df1 :

id name
1  200/300A/200B
2  805/805B/500

df2 :

ids
805
200B

Now I want to replace df1 names with df2 ids as 0, for example where ever the data present as 805 and 200B there in dataframe1 needs to replace with zero.
out put should be
df 

id name
1  200/300A/0
2  0/805B/500


Check below code.
df1
.join(df2.selectExpr("collect_set(ids) AS ids"))
.withColumn(
    "name", 
    expr("concat_ws('/', transform(split(name, '/'), s -> if(array_contains(ids,s), 0, s)))")
)
.select("id", "name")
.show(false)

+---+----------+
|id |name      |
+---+----------+
|1  |200/300A/0|
|2  |0/805B/500|
+---+----------+

Updated
df
.join(df2.selectExpr("collect_set(ids) AS ids"))
.withColumn(
    "name", 
    expr("concat_ws('/', transform(split(name, '/'), s -> if(array_contains(ids,s), 0, 1)))")
)
.select("id", "name")
.show(false)

+---+-----+
|id |name |
+---+-----+
|1  |1/1/0|
|2  |0/1/1|
+---+-----+


This is working as expected. Thanks for that. I forget to mention in begin where ever the value present it should be "0", not present it should be "1". Expected should be 1, 1/1/0
2 0/1/1

Thanks for update perfectly working. today morning I saw some names in df1 coming differently, for example 3, 20B+500, in this it is replacing as "1", desired out put should be 1+0, sorry for informing this as early state, now data is coming interms of "/" and also some times with + and also without + and /. Finally i need to replace df2 values with "0" in df1 without considering the form of string. Please help me on this. sorry for making you trouble. Thanks
